# Java Play sbt-digest for caching js files by content change

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working on a java play 2.5.x project with webpack as the client side build tool, which generates the app.js and vendor.js

I am trying to make the play framework apply some sort of browser caching to the files, meaning i would like the play to respond with a 304 Not Modified header when the app.js and the vendor.js files did not change. And when a change is made i want it to invalidate the files from caching in the clients browsers.

I tried to add the sbt-digest plugin in play, but after i build the files again using webpack, play responds with an 200 OK and not 304 Not Modified.

this is what i added: 
in **build.sbt**:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
  .settings(jacoco.settings: _*)

pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(digest)
```

in **plugins.sbt**:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
```

in routes:

```
GET /cmtb/assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

in **main.scala.html**

```
if(appConfig.get(ApplicationController.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ENABLED).asInstanceOf[Boolean]) {
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/dist/app.js"></script>
} else {
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("client/dist/vendor.js")"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("client/dist/app.js")"></script>
}
```